# Error ubuntu 20.04 lock sreen break layout

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

I don't know when it happens but now, [My lock sreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBJ23.jpg) looks like a website with lost CSS file.
Please help me to restore my lock screen.

Comment: is that just the screen where you usually enter your password, or also the screen before that? (Assuming ubuntu 20 has it the same as my ubuntu 18)

Comment: @lucidbrot 20.04 has GNOME 3.36. GNOME removed curtain style lockscreen in 3.36 instead it now has blur effect. See [this video](https://youtu.be/ae2D4aWTsXM?t=84) by GNOME.

Comment: Yes, the lock screen in the new gnome has blur effect. But you can see my lock screen, The avatar, and password input box style error look like a lost CSS file. And just Lock Screen and Login Screen has this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. It happened after I installed a gnome extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1238/time/

If you encounter the same problem, Remove this extension and the problem will fix